# Multiple async calls blocking

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-3.6

My code:

```
import asyncio

async def test(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    print('test')

async def main():
    await test(2)
    await test(2)
    await test(2)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever(main())
```

I was expecting for it to sleep for three seconds, then print out `'test'` three times, but instead it waits 2 seconds before every `'test'` separately (so last `'test'` gets printed at 6 seconds).

What have I understood wrong, and how do I fix this to work as I expected?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`await` suspends the execution of the current function until the future has returned. In `test`, that makes the function wait for 2 seconds until `asyncio.sleep` has returned, before printing. In `main`, it makes the function wait until `test` has returned (which it does after `print` which it does after `sleep` has returned), before continuing on the next line with the next `await test`.

If you want to execute all `test` at the same time and have them each print at once after two seconds, you can use `asyncio.gather`:

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test(2), test(2), test(2))
```

This schedules three `test` coroutines on the event loop at the same time and awaits all their combined results, which will arrive in ~2 seconds.

You could also fire and forget the coroutines without awaiting their completion:

```
def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(test(2))
    asyncio.ensure_future(test(2))
    asyncio.ensure_future(test(2))
```